# save the previous state to one array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reactjs

I have a class that gets the available funds on the account from the REST API. This number is saved in state.

I need to create a separate state in which I will store the array of all state changes

For example, my state `availableFunds` is: `86`
So I would like, that my `availableFundsArray` returns: `[86]`

If my state `availableFunds` changes the number to eg: 60
So I would like, that my `availableFundsArray` returns: `[86, 60]`

```
class AvailableFunds extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      availableFunds: [],
      availableFundsArray: [],
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.Auth.availableFunds(this.props.id)
      .then(res => {
        if (res) {
          this.setState({
            availableFunds: res.reduce(
              (accumulator, currentValue) =>
                accumulator + currentValue.available_funds,
              0,
            ),
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy I know I need to make concatenations, but I don't know, whether it should be a new method, or do it when it saves availablefunds state.

Answer (score 1):

When you set setState, reference the previous form of the state and add onto it.

Have availableFunds be a Number not an array.

```
let funds = [this.state.availableFunds];

funds.push(this.state.availableFunds)

this.setState({
    availableFundsArray: funds
})
```

Comment: It's not working, because in `this.state.availableFunds` is my value of MySQL databases and I don't use `setState` to change this variable. This variable changes dynamically, when I change this value into db.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if statement you can calculate before the **setState** the funds available and use that variable to update the state with the prevState as below

```
this.Auth.availableFunds(this.props.id)
      .then(res => {
        if (res) {
            const amount = res.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.available_funds, 0, )

            this.setState( prevState => {
            return {
                availableFunds: amount,
                availableFundsArray: [...prevState.availableFundsArray, amount]
            }
          });
        }
      })
     .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: Yes this answer looks good too. I like the use of the spread operator and separating the amount into a variable.

Comment: It's not working, because in this.state.availableFunds is my value of MySQL databases and I don't use setState to change this variable. This variable changes dynamically, when I change this value into db, because this is my response from REST API.

Comment: It is not very clear what are trying to accomplish, both answers do not change the value received from the REST API, it just stores it in the state.